# Decompose maximum function?

Tags: analysis

If $a,b,k \in \mathbb{R}$, is there a way to write the expression $$\max(a-kb,0)$$ as $$\max(a-b,0)+kf(a,b)$$ for some function f?
I am looking to factor out $k$ from inside the max expression, but I haven't had any luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that can't work, for several reasons.

First consider $k=0$, that means you want to have $\max(a,0)=\max(a-b,0)$, which may not be true.

But more generally, if $a,b$ are fixed, then $g(k)=\max(a-b,0)+kf(a,b)$ is a linear function in $k$ (fixed term $\max(a-b,0)$ and slope $f(a,b)$), while $h(k)=\max(a-kb,0)$ is (generally) not, it's 2 pieces; one's a linear function, the other the constant function ($0$) function.

The only case when $h(k)$ is linear is when $b=0$, then $h(k)$ is a constant. Then you can choose $f(a,b)=0$. But in general this is not possible.

Comment: Thanks! That helped.